# Set size of \colorbox for a single character

Tags: color, boxes, characters, size

my question is simple (or not) I want to set the size of the `\colorbox` command or `\fcolorbox` command for a single character. The problem is the next:

[image: character box]

As seen in the image, the height and width are different for different characters, but what I want is that the size is the same for all characters. The package that I use is `xcolor`and the code I used to generate the box character is
`\noindent\colorbox{black!85}{\textcolor{white}{i}}`

My objective is a box with individually centred character. The background of the box in black color and text in white. Also would be nice if it is a `enumitem` and the items are in a black box

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
 \colorbox{black!85}{\makebox[2em]{\strut\textcolor{white}{a}}}
```

or any other width that you want.

Or as if indicated in comments you want vertical as well as horizontal centering

```
 \colorbox{black!85}{\makebox(12,12){\textcolor{white}{a}}}
```

where the size of the box, 12, is given in picture environment units (`pt` by default)

Comment: David your solution is a very good and simple solution, but I want a smaller height.

Comment: @Kiyoshi replace `\strut` by `\rule[1pt]{0pt}{5pt}`  replacing 1 and 5 for whatever depth and height you want

Comment: If possible to create a `colorbox` with the same width and height for all character but the characters in center of a box?

Comment: @Kiyoshi makebox centres by default, so the characters should be horizontally centred, and by adjusting the height and depth you use in the strut you can make the baseline be wherever you want or do you want an A to be lower than an a so they are individually centred rather than being on the same baseline?

Comment: Exactly, I want a individually centred.

Comment: @Kiyoshi I updated the answer:-)

Answer (score 8):

With `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\coloredtext[2][]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[minimum width=2em,text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.1ex,fill=black!85,text=white,#1](char){#2};}%
\begin{document}
\noindent
\foreach \x in {a,b,...,z}{%
   \coloredtext{\x}\,
   }

\noindent
\foreach \x in {A,B,...,Z}{%
   \coloredtext[minimum width=2.55em]{\x}
   }%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can control perfectly the width and the height, if is possible to center the character in a box that would be amazing ;)

Comment: @Kiyoshi They are already centered horizontally by default.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using the `eqparbox` package, if you want to have equal and minimal widths  of the boxes (two runs are required):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier} 

\usepackage{eqparbox} 
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor} 

\begin{document}

\colorbox{DeepPink4}{\eqmakebox[L]{\Large\bfseries\color{AntiqueWhite1}I}}

\colorbox{DeepPink4}{\eqmakebox[L]{\Large\bfseries\color{AntiqueWhite1}W}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the coloured boxes to have the same heights, while keeping the natural width of the widest, you can adjust the height in two ways:

- Either insert a `\vphantom{highest entry}` as an argument to `eqmakebox`. Of course, it's up to you to decide which will be the highest entry. One may turn it into an optional argument of a macro.
- Or insert an invisible rule that lets you predefine the height of the box.

I give an example of both, the second solution with predefined height equal to 1 cm. This can make possible fancy effects.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\colorbox{DeepPink4}{\eqmakebox[L]{\Large\bfseries\color{AntiqueWhite1}I}}
\enspace 
\colorbox{DeepPink4}{\eqmakebox[L]{\Large\bfseries\color{AntiqueWhite1}W}}
\enspace 
\colorbox{DeepPink4}{\eqmakebox[L]{\vphantom{\Large\bfseries W}\footnotesize\bfseries\color{AntiqueWhite1}W}}
\enspace\\

\colorbox{AntiqueWhite1}{\eqmakebox[L]{\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr 1cm-2\fboxsep\relax}\Large\bfseries\color{DeepPink4}W}}
\enspace
\colorbox{AntiqueWhite1}{\eqmakebox[L]{\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr 1cm-2\fboxsep\relax}\footnotesize\bfseries\color{DeepPink4}i}}
\enspace\\

\colorbox{AntiqueWhite1}{\eqmakebox[L]{\rule[-0.4cm]{0pt}{\dimexpr 1cm-2\fboxsep\relax}\Large\bfseries\color{DeepPink4}W}}
\enspace
\colorbox{AntiqueWhite1}{\eqmakebox[L]{\rule[-0.4cm]{0pt}{\dimexpr 1cm-2\fboxsep\relax}\footnotesize\bfseries\color{DeepPink4}i}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with `eqparbox` is when I adjust the box to a character  normal size the height is not equal.

Comment: @ Kiyoshi: Do you mean that if your letters have different sizes, hence differnt heights,  the height of the coloured boxes will be different, and you'd like it to be the same?

Comment: @ Bernard: Same size and centred

Comment: @Kiyoshi: Updated my answer. I added two solutions to the height problem.

Answer (score 3):

The first optional argument is the textcolor and the second is the background color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\def\Cbox{\@ifnextchar[\Cbox@i{\Cbox@i[white]}}
\def\Cbox@i[#1]{\@ifnextchar[{\Cbox@ii[#1]}{\Cbox@ii[#1][black]}}
\def\Cbox@ii[#1][#2]#3{\colorbox{#2}{\makebox[1em]{\strut\textcolor{#1}{#3}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\Cbox{I} \Cbox[yellow]{g} \Cbox[AntiqueWhite1][DeepPink4]{W}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, but I want a smaller height box.

Answer (score 2):

Here a solution with the `adjustbox` package. You can create the centered box using the `center=<width>` key. Adding `\strut` gives you the same height and depths independent of the character size. If you use `\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox` as the width you will get a nice square.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand\blackboxchar[1]{\noindent
    \adjustbox{center=\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox,frame,bgcolor=black!85}{\color{white}\strut #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item[\blackboxchar{i}] text  text  text  text 

\item[\blackboxchar{a}] text  text  text  text 

\item[\blackboxchar{m}] text  text  text  text 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]