# tcolorbox with fancy text

Tags: errors, verbatim, tcolorbox, backgrounds, text-decorations

Driven from [Let's get fancy: Text like tag?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311934/lets-get-fancy-text-like-tag) , I wrote this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.122, 0.435, 0.698}

\newtcbox{\mybox}{nobeforeafter,colframe=mycolor,colback=mycolor!10!white,boxrule=0.5pt,arc=4pt,
  boxsep=-3pt,left=6pt,right=6pt,top=6pt,bottom=6pt,tcbox raise base}

\begin{document}
\mybox{C{}\verb!++!}
\end{document}
```

The error:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.9 \mybox{C{}\verb!++!}
```

This works with normal text inside the box, but because of the fancy way I am trying to write C++ and the fancy textbox, I am getting fancy² and I overflow! :) Any ideas?

Comment: You can't use verbatim code like this in the command argument of `tcbox`

Comment: The error I get from that code is `! LaTeX Error: \verb illegal in command argument.`.

Comment: Oh damn, any workaround @ChristianHupfer to keep `tcbox` and still have a fancy C++ text?

Comment: `\tcboxverb` is what you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\texttt{++}` instead, can't you?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.122, 0.435, 0.698}

\newtcbox{\mybox}{nobeforeafter,colframe=mycolor,colback=mycolor!10!white,boxrule=0.5pt,arc=4pt,
  boxsep=-3pt,left=6pt,right=6pt,top=6pt,bottom=6pt,tcbox raise base}

\begin{document}
\mybox{C\texttt{++}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works. Christian's solution should work for newer installations than mine's!

Answer (score 4):

I hope, at least this compiles for the O.P. ;-)

`\tcboxverb` is designed for such small boxes with verbatim content.

I've added a `myboxstyle` TikZ style for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.122, 0.435, 0.698}

%\newtcbox{\mybox}{nobeforeafter,colframe=mycolor,colback=mycolor!10!white,boxrule=0.5pt,arc=4pt,
%  boxsep=-3pt,left=6pt,right=6pt,top=6pt,bottom=6pt,tcbox raise base}

\tcbset{myboxstyle/.style={%
nobeforeafter,colframe=mycolor,colback=mycolor!10!white,boxrule=0.5pt,arc=4pt,
  boxsep=-3pt,left=6pt,right=6pt,top=6pt,bottom=6pt,tcbox raise base
}}

\begin{document}
\tcboxverb[myboxstyle]{C++}

\tcboxverb[myboxstyle]{#include <iostream>}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `l.14 \tcboxverb` gets an undefined control sequence. You can't escape your faith Christian. Danke!