# Partition the box'ed text items!

Tags: backgrounds, text-decorations, text-manipulation, text, tags

After the [Let's get fancy: Text like tag?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311934/lets-get-fancy-text-like-tag), I am thinking that it would be nice to have a sequence of boxes, let's say 5 in number and be able to partition them in the first 2 and the rest 3, for example.

That means we will need a delimiter... A (colored) dashed thin line?

I have no idea how to implement that, can you help please?

---

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.122, 0.435, 0.698}

\newtcbox{\mybox}{nobeforeafter,colframe=mycolor,colback=mycolor!10!white,boxrule=0.5pt,arc=4pt,
  boxsep=-3pt,left=6pt,right=6pt,top=6pt,bottom=5pt,tcbox raise base}


\begin{document}

\mybox{coolText0} \mybox{coolText1} \mybox{coolText2} \mybox{coolText3} \mybox{coolText4}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, something like this, in the form of `\mystrut` or `\mydashstrut`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox,stackengine}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.122, 0.435, 0.698}

\newtcbox{\mybox}{nobeforeafter,colframe=mycolor,colback=mycolor!10!white,boxrule=0.5pt,arc=4pt,
  boxsep=-3pt,left=6pt,right=6pt,top=6pt,bottom=5pt,tcbox raise base}
\newcommand\mystrut{{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\,\color{red}%
  \fbox{\rule[-3pt]{0pt}{13pt}}\,}}
\newcommand\mydashstrut{{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\,\color{red}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{5pt}}}\abovebaseline[-3pt]{%
  \stackon{\copy0}{\copy0}\,}}}

\begin{document}

\mybox{coolText0} \mybox{coolText1} \mybox{coolText2}\mystrut 
  \mybox{coolText3} \mybox{coolText4}\medskip

\mybox{coolText0} \mybox{coolText1} \mybox{coolText2}\mydashstrut  
  \mybox{coolText3} \mybox{coolText4}
\end{document}
```

[image]

p.s.  I am assuming the "cool text" boxes remain a single line high.  If that is not the case, please advise.